# XMPP client on android: potential battery issues

Tags: android, xmpp, battery, whatsapp

I am new to the android development. I am implementing a XMPP client to talk to the XJabberd service running on my server. I believe it is going to maintain a persistent connection to the server which (afaik) will need to periodically send the keep alive messages.

Is that a concern for the battery life? I believe it is and GCM is the way to reduce that impact. However, GCM will not guarantee
1. immediate delivery and
2. maintaining of the messages sent while the device is offline

Is there any other alternative/approach to reduce the battery impact. Any document which explains the engineering aspect of the Whatsapp app?

Comment: WhatsApp isn't XMPP. With full control over the server, they can use push notifications just fine without losing messages.

Comment: The question is how often you will check the connection by sending server pings or whitespace keep-alives. This is the major contributing factor to the battery consumption caused by the persistent connection.

Comment: @323go It must be some variant of XMPP I believe. Irrespective of that, as Flow mentioned, the XMPP client will need to keep sending keep alive messages to the server but I don't see Whatsapp in my top battery consuming apps ever. Does that mean the battery consumption because of this is minimal compared to other apps

Comment: You're missing the main point of my comment -- Private Silos like WhatsApp *are not bound* by the same limitations you are if you follow a standard, such as XMPP. If you have full control over how your server acts, then you don't need to have the client keep the connection alive as frequently. Clients can be alerted through push-notifications, or might hold comet connections for low latency responses.

Comment: I think I understand your point now. Just to confirm if my understanding is correct, I believe what you are suggesting is: To save battery there is no need to keep the connection up all the time. However, server can send the push notification (say using GCM) and on receiving this notification client can bring back the connectivity. However, this will not  *guarantee* instant communication. This sounds good to me. Thanks!

Comment: "client will need to keep sending keep alive messages" What makes you think that the client needs to send keep alive messages? If at all it's usually sufficient to send a ping every 30 minutes if there was no activity within the last 30 minutes (Smack's ServerPingWithAlarmManager will do that automatically for you).

Comment: "To save battery there is no need to keep the connection up all the time. However, server can send the push notification (say using GCM) and on receiving this notification client can bring back the connectivity." I believe that this is the wrong approach. GCM does nothing else then keep a connection open to the GCM Server, you can do the same with XMPP.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe it is going to maintain a persistent connection to the
>   server which (afaik) will need to periodically send the keep alive
>   messages.

You don't "need" that. In my experience it's enough to send an XMPP Ping to the server every 30 minutes *if there has been no activity within that time*. Smack's [ServerPingWithAlarmManager](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/dailybuilds/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ping/android/ServerPingWithAlarmManager.html) does that for automatically you.

You always have a trade off between how long you want "stale" connections to be undetected and how often you test if the TCP connection is still alive. There is no mechanism or entity that can avoid deciding for either of those, not even GCM or WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

> immediate delivery
>
> maintaining of the messages

CGM should be used to send **notifications** about existing messages, **not**  messages itself. **Your** server should maintain messages, and use GCM for notifications. Even if user will not receive notification, it will receive messages on the next XMPP connection.